# Using css selectors to grab nested tag on Reactjs page using scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to grab the highlighted `href` value using CSS selectors but am currently unsuccessful.

I am using `scrapy shell` and tried this:

`response.css('body > span > section')` but it returns `[]`

I also tried `response.css('div')` to see if it can grab any `div` tag but it still returns `[]`

Using chrome's devtool to grab the css selector returned

`#react-root > section > main > article > div > div._cmdpi > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a`

I used `response.css()` against chrome's provided css but it also returned `[]`

However, when I try:

`response.css('body, span, section, main, article, div, div, div')`

I am returned this:

```
[<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::body | descendant-or-self::span | descendant-or-self::section | descendant-or-self::main | descendant-or-self::article | descendant-or-self::div | descendant-or-self::div | descendant-or-self::div' data='<body class="">\n        \n    <span id="r'>, <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::body | descendant-or-self::span | descendant-or-self::section | descendant-or-self::main | descendant-or-self::article | descendant-or-self::div | descendant-or-self::div | descendant-or-self::div' data='<span id="react-root"></span>'>]
```

I am quite confused as to why certain css selectors work and why others do not. Like `div` versus `body, span, section, main, article, div, div, div`

[image]

Comment: Can you use bs4? `select_one('a[href*=taken-by]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason is because the html code that you see in your browser is probably generated on the client side using javascript. I would recommend you to inspect the html received with scrapy (you can save the `response.body` in a file if you want) or inspect it in the shell. 
The `,` inside a css selector is something like an `or` statement. The data needed for that href is probably in a json inside the html code.